# Java PriorityQueue comparator

Tags: java

Say that I have an `shoeCollection` class that has both the shoe size and the shoe brand. how do I modify the comparator such that it will sort the `priorityQueue` based on shoe size?

I know that priority queues already have a build-in comparator, but since my object is not an Integer or Double, I figured I need to write my own.

This is my comparator right now

```
static class ShoeComparator implements Comparator<shoes>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(shoes x, shoes y)
    {
        if(x.getID() > y.getID()){
            return 1;
        }
        if(x.getID() < y.getID()){
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I then declare a new Shoe priority queue with  the following

```
private static Comparator<shoes> comparator = new shoeComparator();
private static PriorityQueue<shoes> list = new PriorityQueue<shoes>(10001, comparator);
```

I tried adding some shoes and see how it will turn out

```
    list.add(new shoes(56.0, "Nike"));
    list.add(new shoes(47.0, "Addidas"));
    list.add(new shoes(93.0, "Puma"));
    list.add(new shoes(3.0, "Vans"));
```

Test it in Main

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(list.poll().getID());

    }

//3.0 47.0
```

Only ID with 3.0 and 47.0 has been registered. Is there something wrong with my Comparator?

It seems like it will only return the first 2 ID and ignore the rest, but when I call upon `list.size()` it returns 4, which is correct. I can't locate the problem.

Comment: What have you tried? How is it not working? What errors are you seeing? Where are you stuck exactly? Do you know how to make Comparator's in general? Please help us help you!

Comment: How was this never answered?  The issue is that list.poll() is removing the head element from the queue, so the size of the list is decreasing inside the loop... so the loop conditions executed are: 0 < 4, 1 < 3, and finally 2 < 2... this is why you only get two executions of the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `PriorityQueue` and in the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue%28int,%20java.util.Comparator%29) put comparator code.

Example:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(10, new Comparator<Integer>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2)
    {
        // Logic here
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom comparator inline during PriorityQueue instantiation.

Assuming your Shoe class looks like the following:

```
public class Shoe {
    private double size;
    private String brand;

    public Shoe(double size, String brand) {
        this.size = size;
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public double getSize() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

You can create a PriorityQueue that orders the shoes by size by doing the following:

```
PriorityQueue<Shoe> shoePQ = new PriorityQueue<>(10000, new Comparator<Shoe>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Shoe s1, Shoe s2) {
        return s1.getSize()-s2.getSize();
    });
}
```

This will order the shoes smallest to largest. If you wanted the reverse order, you would replace the body of `compare()` with `return s2.getSize()-s1.getSize();`